# How to run a different storyboard (other than main)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have created a new storyboard. I don't want to connect it with main right now but want to execute it in the simulator. However, every time I create the build only the main storyboard is executed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some of the code or configuration you've attempted to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things you could do but having more context would be helpful. Is this purely for testing purposes while you build out the storyboard or are you wanting to switch them permanently?

But for simplicity(and I hope this covers everything), this is generally how you do that:

1. **Navigate to the project file on the left hand pane**

[image]

2. **Go to General -> Deployment Info -> Main Interface** and change the drop down selection from 'Main' to the storyboard you want to be directed to on launch
   [image]
3. **Go to the storyboard you're wanting to display** and add a storyboard entry point (this is the little arrow next to the ViewController by default on your main storyboard). You can add this by going to inspector panel in attributes section on the right, click "Is initial View Controller" under the View Controller section. Make sure to delete the arrow on the Main storyboard as well!

[image]
[image]

4. **Add Storyboard name in info.plist** by going to Application scene manifest -> Scene Configuration -> Application Session Role -> Item -> Storyboard Name and change that to your desired storyboard name.

[image]